# When terminate celery chain conditionally, it not return the data

Tags: python, celery, workflow, celery-canvas

I have chain of tasks, and want to terminate conditionally, I am following steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21106596/243031 but after that, we are not getting the output.

I have tasks as

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app


@app.task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
    if (x + y) % 2 == 0:
        self.request.callbacks[:] = []
    return x + y
```

means when the sum is even and its part of chain, then stop that chain.

But it gives error.

```
In [13]: ~(add.s(2, 2) | add.s(3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-0fe85c5d0e22> in <module>
----> 1 ~(add.s(2, 2) | add.s(3))

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py in __invert__(self)
    479
    480     def __invert__(self):
--> 481         return self.apply_async().get()
    482
    483     def __reduce__(self):

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py in get(self, timeout, propagate, interval, no_ack, follow_parents, callback, on_message, on_interval, disable_sync_subtasks, EXCEPTION_STATES, PROPAGATE_STATES)
    228             propagate=propagate,
    229             callback=callback,
--> 230             on_message=on_message,
    231         )
    232     wait = get  # deprecated alias to :meth:`get`.

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py in wait_for_pending(self, result, callback, propagate, **kwargs)
    197                          callback=None, propagate=True, **kwargs):
    198         self._ensure_not_eager()
--> 199         for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):
    200             pass
    201         return result.maybe_throw(callback=callback, propagate=propagate)

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py in _wait_for_pending(self, result, timeout, on_interval, on_message, **kwargs)
    265             for _ in self.drain_events_until(
    266                     result.on_ready, timeout=timeout,
--> 267                     on_interval=on_interval):
    268                 yield
    269                 sleep(0)

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py in drain_events_until(self, p, timeout, interval, on_interval, wait)
     56                 pass
     57             if on_interval:
---> 58                 on_interval()
     59             if p.ready:  # got event on the wanted channel.
     60                 break

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    158                     self.value = (ca, ck) = (retval,), {}
    159             except Exception:
--> 160                 return self.throw()
    161         else:
    162             self.value = (ca, ck) = final_args, final_kwargs

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    155                     ck = {}
    156                 else:
--> 157                     retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
    158                     self.value = (ca, ck) = (retval,), {}
    159             except Exception:

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py in _maybe_reraise_parent_error(self)
    234     def _maybe_reraise_parent_error(self):
    235         for node in reversed(list(self._parents())):
--> 236             node.maybe_throw()
    237
    238     def _parents(self):

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py in maybe_throw(self, propagate, callback)
    333             cache['status'], cache['result'], cache.get('traceback'))
    334         if state in states.PROPAGATE_STATES and propagate:
--> 335             self.throw(value, self._to_remote_traceback(tb))
    336         if callback is not None:
    337             callback(self.id, value)

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py in throw(self, *args, **kwargs)
    326
    327     def throw(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 328         self.on_ready.throw(*args, **kwargs)
    329
    330     def maybe_throw(self, propagate=True, callback=None):

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py in throw(self, exc, tb, propagate)
    232                     if tb is None and (exc is None or exc is current_exc):
    233                         raise
--> 234                     reraise(type(exc), exc, tb)
    235
    236     @property

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/utils.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
     28     if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
     29         raise value.with_traceback(tb)
---> 30     raise value

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

I tried `self.request.chain = None` and `self.request.chain[:] = []`,

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def add(self, x, y):
    if self.request.chain and (x + y) % 2 == 0:
        self.request.chain = None
    return x + y
```

In logs, it shows, it return the data.

[2021-03-24 22:11:48,795: WARNING/MainProcess] Substantial drift from scrpc_worker@458cd596aed3 may mean clocks are out of sync.  Current drift is
14400 seconds.  [orig: 2021-03-24 22:11:48.795402 recv: 2021-03-25 02:11:48.796579]

```
[2021-03-24 22:11:52,227: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
[2021-03-24 22:11:57,853: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: myprj.tasks.add[8aaae68f-d5ca-4c0a-8f2e-f1c7b5916e29]
[2021-03-24 22:11:57,867: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task myprj.tasks.add[8aaae68f-d5ca-4c0a-8f2e-f1c7b5916e29] succeeded in 0.01066690299999884s: 4
```

but it wait for some socket and when we press `ctr+c`, it give below traceback.

```
In [1]: from myprj.tasks import add

In [2]: ~(add.s(2, 2) | add.s(3))
^C---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0fe85c5d0e22> in <module>
----> 1 ~(add.s(2, 2) | add.s(3))

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py in __invert__(self)
    479
    480     def __invert__(self):
--> 481         return self.apply_async().get()
    482
    483     def __reduce__(self):

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py in get(self, timeout, propagate, interval, no_ack, follow_parents, callback, on_message, on_interval, disable_sync_subtasks, EXCEPTION_STATES, PROPAGATE_STATES)
    228             propagate=propagate,
    229             callback=callback,
--> 230             on_message=on_message,
    231         )
    232     wait = get  # deprecated alias to :meth:`get`.

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py in wait_for_pending(self, result, callback, propagate, **kwargs)
    197                          callback=None, propagate=True, **kwargs):
    198         self._ensure_not_eager()
--> 199         for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):
    200             pass
    201         return result.maybe_throw(callback=callback, propagate=propagate)

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py in _wait_for_pending(self, result, timeout, on_interval, on_message, **kwargs)
    265             for _ in self.drain_events_until(
    266                     result.on_ready, timeout=timeout,
--> 267                     on_interval=on_interval):
    268                 yield
    269                 sleep(0)

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py in drain_events_until(self, p, timeout, interval, on_interval, wait)
     52                 raise socket.timeout()
     53             try:
---> 54                 yield self.wait_for(p, wait, timeout=interval)
     55             except socket.timeout:
     56                 pass

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py in wait_for(self, p, wait, timeout)
     61
     62     def wait_for(self, p, wait, timeout=None):
---> 63         wait(timeout=timeout)
     64
     65

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py in drain_events(self, timeout)
    149         if self._pubsub:
    150             with self.reconnect_on_error():
--> 151                 message = self._pubsub.get_message(timeout=timeout)
    152                 if message and message['type'] == 'message':
    153                     self.on_state_change(self._decode_result(message['data']), message)

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py in get_message(self, ignore_subscribe_messages, timeout)
   3615         number.
   3616         """
-> 3617         response = self.parse_response(block=False, timeout=timeout)
   3618         if response:
   3619             return self.handle_message(response, ignore_subscribe_messages)

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/client.py in parse_response(self, block, timeout)
   3501         self.check_health()
   3502
-> 3503         if not block and not conn.can_read(timeout=timeout):
   3504             return None
   3505         response = self._execute(conn, conn.read_response)

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py in can_read(self, timeout)
    732             self.connect()
    733             sock = self._sock
--> 734         return self._parser.can_read(timeout)
    735
    736     def read_response(self):

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py in can_read(self, timeout)
    319
    320     def can_read(self, timeout):
--> 321         return self._buffer and self._buffer.can_read(timeout)
    322
    323     def read_response(self):

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py in can_read(self, timeout)
    229         return bool(self.length) or \
    230             self._read_from_socket(timeout=timeout,
--> 231                                    raise_on_timeout=False)
    232
    233     def read(self, length):

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py in _read_from_socket(self, length, timeout, raise_on_timeout)
    196                 sock.settimeout(timeout)
    197             while True:
--> 198                 data = recv(self._sock, socket_read_size)
    199                 # an empty string indicates the server shutdown the socket
    200                 if isinstance(data, bytes) and len(data) == 0:

~/virtualenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redis/_compat.py in recv(sock, *args, **kwargs)
     70 else:  # Python 3.5 and above automatically retry EINTR
     71     def recv(sock, *args, **kwargs):
---> 72         return sock.recv(*args, **kwargs)
     73
     74     def recv_into(sock, *args, **kwargs):

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

First of all, terminating chain is good option or we have to add condition in next chain task that if some condition, don't process, just return what you get.

If we have to terminate the chain, what is the best option? where you get the output of partial chain.