# Celery: clean way of revoking the entire chain from within a task

Tags: django, task, celery, chain

My question is probably pretty basic but still I can't get a solution in the official doc. I have defined a Celery chain inside my Django application, performing a set of tasks dependent from eanch other:

```
chain(  tasks.apply_fetching_decision.s(x, y),
        tasks.retrieve_public_info.s(z, x, y),
        tasks.public_adapter.s())()
```

Obviously the second and the third tasks need the output of the parent, that's why I used a chain.

Now the question: I need to programmatically **revoke** the 2nd and the 3rd tasks if a test condition in the 1st task fails. How to do it in a clean way? I know I can revoke the tasks of a chain from within the method where I have defined the chain (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772556/celery-task-chain-cancelling)question and [this doc](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains)) but **inside** the first task I have no visibility of subsequent tasks nor of the chain itself.

#### Temporary solution

My current solution is to **skip** the computation inside the subsequent tasks based on result of the previous task:

```
@shared_task
def retrieve_public_info(result, x, y):
   if not result:
      return []
   ...

@shared_task
def public_adapter(result, z, x, y):
   for r in result:
       ...
```

But this "workaround" has some flaw:

- Adds unnecessary logic to each task (based on predecessor's result), compromising reuse
- Still *executes* the subsequent tasks, with all the resulting overhead

I haven't played too much with passing references of the chain to tasks for fear of messing up things. I admit also I haven't tried Exception-throwing approach, because I think that the choice of not proceeding through the chain can be a functional (thus non exceptional) scenario...

Thanks for helping!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Celery stop execution of a chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461374/celery-stop-execution-of-a-chain)

Comment: Rather than passing only the value of the result, you can pass a tuple of the result and a success message. In higher terms, this can be implemented as an Error Monad or a Maybe Monad: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads#The_Error_monad http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#The_Maybe_monad

Comment: This doesn't prevent the N subsequent chain tasks to be executed. What I am trying to avoid is exactly the overhead of tasks to be called and executed in vain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I found *the* answer to this issue: **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21106596/2200058)** seems the right way to proceed, indeed. I wonder why such common scenario is not documented anywhere, though.

For completeness I post the basic code snapshot:

```
@app.task(bind=True)  # Note that we need bind=True for self to work
def task1(self, other_args):
    #do_stuff
    if end_chain:
        self.request.callbacks[:] = []
    ....
```

### Update

I implemented a more elegant way to cope with the issue and I want to share it with you. I am using a decorator called `revoke_chain_authority`, so that it can revoke automatically the chain without rewriting the code I previously described.

```
from functools import wraps

class RevokeChainRequested(Exception):
    def __init__(self, return_value):
        Exception.__init__(self, "")

        # Now for your custom code...
        self.return_value = return_value


def revoke_chain_authority(a_shared_task):
    """
    @see: https://gist.github.com/bloudermilk/2173940
    @param a_shared_task: a @shared_task(bind=True) celery function.
    @return:
    """
    @wraps(a_shared_task)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return a_shared_task(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except RevokeChainRequested, e:
            # Drop subsequent tasks in chain (if not EAGER mode)
            if self.request.callbacks:
                self.request.callbacks[:] = []
            return e.return_value

    return inner
```

This decorator can be used on a **`shared task`** as follows:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
@revoke_chain_authority
def apply_fetching_decision(self, latitude, longitude):
    #...

    if condition:
        raise RevokeChainRequested(False)
```

Please **note** the use of `@wraps`. It is necessary to preserve the signature of the original function, otherwise this latter will be lost and `celery` will make a mess at calling the right wrapped task (e.g. it will call always the first registered function instead of the right one)

Answer (score 18):

As of Celery 4.0, what I found to be working is to remove the remaining tasks from the current [task instance's request](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-request) using the statement:

```
self.request.chain = None
```

Let's say you have a chain of tasks `a.s() | b.s() | c.s()`. You can only access the `self` variable inside a task if you [bind the task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks) by passing `bind=True` as argument to the tasks' decorator.

```
@app.task(name='main.a', bind=True):
def a(self):
  if something_happened:
    self.request.chain = None
```

If `something_happened` is truthy, `b` and `c` wouldn't be executed.

Comment: and how it should be used? For example: I have a ID, which returned by chain_task.apply_async(), what can I do to revoke this task?

Comment: @ailin Just edited the answer. I don't know how to revoke a task by its id. This solution is useful if you need to stop the chain conditionally inside some task.

Comment: oh, I got it thanks. Btw, I found approach that not elegant, but helped for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23908345/6696051

Comment: I wonder how “official” this solution is; feels somewhat hacky to me. While it seems to work I can’t find documentation that this is a supported way of aborting a chain of tasks...

Comment: If I have this chain in a group and I set `self.request.chain = None`, I only want that to stop this chain, but not affect the rest of the parallel group. Will that statement correctly only affect the current chain?

Comment: @rasen58 I also have a chain inside another chain and in my case it stop the two chains.