# revoke celery chain eager mode

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am using `celery chain` in Django project.

For chained tasks, I am using `task_postrun` signal to revoke all subsequent tasks [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40579984/7948857).

```
@task_postrun.connect
def task_postrun_handler(
    signal, sender, task_id, task, retval, state, args, kwargs, **kwds
):
    # do other things first
    if retval != 1:
        task.request.chain[:] = []
```

So if the task's return value is not 1, then revoke all the subsequent tasks. It works fine.

However, in my test, I run the tasks in eager mode. It does enter the 
`task_postrun_handler`, but doesn't have array of `chain` ( the `callbacks` is `None` as well).

In this way, I am not able to terminate the task chains in my test.
I tried both in `celery 3.1.23` and `celery 4.0.2`

Thanks for any help.